# Would initializing sortable widget more than once be detrimental?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a situation where I need an element, that is not yet created, to be sortable when it is created.  So in my code I call the sortable widget everytime that new element is created.  Will this have any detrimental effects, or does it simply overwrite the previous version of the widget?

Example Code:

```
function createNewElement(){
    $("#myDiv").append("<li class="newElement"></li>");

    $(".newElement").sortable({
        //various options here
    });
}

$("#clickThis").click(function(){ createNewElement(); });
```

If it is detrimental, then how do I only initialize the sortable widget once when the first element is created?

**Edit**:

I would use `sortable("refresh")` if the sortable widget were already initiated, but because the element that the sortable widget is initiated on does not exist yet I get errors saying 'you cannot call a method on a sortable widget that has not been initialized yet'

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this

```
function createNewElement(){
    $("<li class="newElement"></li>")
      .appendTo("#myDiv").sortable({...});
}

$("#clickThis").click(function(){ createNewElement(); });
```

Comment: `sortable("refresh")` throws an error because I am calling a method on a sortable widget that has not been initialized yet.  This is because the element that the sortable widget would be initialized on does not exist yet. My solution was to initialize the widget every time a new element is made, which seems to work.

Comment: also, I'm calling sortable on a list item just for example sake.

Comment: then why aren't you just initializing the new element?

Comment: I guess that is the question. How do I initialize it on the new element only once?  In my example I initiate it on every new element.

Comment: i modified my answer, does this help?

Comment: wouldn't that have the same problem of initiating the sortable call every time?

Comment: I think the initiating call should be outside of the createNewElement function somehow and the `sortable("refresh")` be in its place. I just don't know how I would do that

Comment: no, because you act on the newly created element an not on all elements with class .newElement. By the way, to be on the safe side you should append first before initializing sortable. I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: I can't see that being any more efficient as it has to run through that whole sortable call everytime. If you can figure a way to get the sortable call out of the function and use refresh then I'll definitely mark your answer. As for now +1 for trying.

Comment: After all this time I still have no Idea what you want. A call to sortable is inevitable, if you want to create a new List with many Items, as seems to be the case from your example. But refresh implies, that you want to add a new Item to an already existing list. This does not show in your example. I'm confused

Comment: I want to create only one list.  The moveable items in that list will be created many times.  I don't know how to make an empty list sortable so in my example I am recreating the same exact sortable list but with a new item in it. Sorry for being so confusing

Comment: You can initialize empty lists as sortable. See here http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/sortable/empty-lists.html . So initialize the list on page load and refresh after adding a new item. Would this work for you?

Comment: that is how I was attempting it, but when I tried to use refresh I got an error saying the method can't be called. Perhaps it has something to do with the nesting of sortables that I am using. Not a big deal as my example seems to get the job done.